# Ionic 2 - few slides components in one page

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to create two "ion-slides" components in one page. But touch scroll works only in one slider. On the second slider, it works only with navigation buttons. How can I make two of the same "ion-slides" components in one page?

Answer (score 0):

All is fine) On device it's working right! Only on browser emulator it's working with wrongs (ionic serve --lab)!